# OpenLayers Map Click won't fire on Android Chrome (Samsung S6 device)

Tags: openlayers, mobile

I'm having an issue getting a map click event to fire properly on a Samsung Galaxy S6 device using Chrome for Android. I have not seen this issue on other devices (yet). I'm using v3.19.1 of the OpenLayers API.

Here's how I create my map and register my click event

```
        CreateMap : function() {
            this.bLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() });
            this.vLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ style:styleFn, source:new ol.source.Vector() });

            var controls = ol.control.defaults({ attributionOptions: { collapsible: true }});
            var view = new ol.View(this.options.view);

            this.map = new ol.Map({
                layers  : [this.bLayer, this.vLayer ],
                controls: controls,
                view    : view
            });

            this.map.on("singleclick", this.onMap_Click.bind(this));

            function styleFn(f) {                   
                return Styles[f.getGeometry().getType()];
            }
        },
```

I tried debugging my device, the code never goes into the onMap_Click function. I've also tried a regular click event.

One thing I noticed is that most of the time, when I'm trying to tap on the map, the map pans a little. If I start tapping furiously on the map, at some point one click event will register properly.

Would moving to the most recent version of OpenLayers help at all?

Comment: Seems you need up versioning. check `moveTolerance` option on `ol.Map`: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/b1b5b54fd08e352e5312ca6626f1c872c3f4cc07/changelog/v4.2.0.md#new-movetolerance-option-in-olmap

Comment: the moveTolerance option in OL4 fixed my issue. Thanks Chase, I'll choose your answer if you make your reply into an actual answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Openlayers added `moveTolerance` option into `ol.Map` to give better click experience on touch devices. check the [change log](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/b1b5b54fd08e352e5312ca6626f1c872c3f4cc07/changelog/v4.2.0.md#new-movetolerance-option-in-olmap) and [documents](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Map.html) for details.

Version up your Openlayers to use `moveTolerance` option.

```
new ol.Map({
    ...
    moveTolerance: 5
})
```